# Position geom_text on dodged barplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I tried to make the title self-explanatory, but here goes - data first:

```
dtf <- structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("vma", "vla", "ia", "fma", "fla"), class = "factor"), 
    ustanova = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("srednja škola", "fakultet"), class = "factor"), 
    `(all)` = c(42.9542857142857, 38.7803203661327, 37.8996138996139, 
    33.7672811059908, 29.591439688716, 26.1890660592255, 27.9557692307692, 
    23.9426605504587, 33.2200772200772, 26.9493087557604)), .Names = c("variable", 
"ustanova", "(all)"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("cast_df", 
"data.frame"), idvars = c("variable", "ustanova"), rdimnames = list(
    structure(list(variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("vma", "vla", "ia", "fma", 
    "fla"), class = "factor"), ustanova = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("srednja škola", 
    "fakultet"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("variable", "ustanova"
    ), row.names = c("vma_srednja škola", "vma_fakultet", "vla_srednja škola", 
    "vla_fakultet", "ia_srednja škola", "ia_fakultet", "fma_srednja škola", 
    "fma_fakultet", "fla_srednja škola", "fla_fakultet"), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(value = structure(1L, .Label = "(all)", class = "factor")), .Names = "value", row.names = "(all)", class = "data.frame")))
```

And I'd like to create a dodged barplot, do the `coord_flip` and put some text labels inside the bars:

```
ggplot(bar) + geom_bar(aes(variable, `(all)`, fill = ustanova), position = "dodge") +
 geom_text(aes(variable, `(all)`, label = sprintf("%2.1f", `(all)`)), position = "dodge") +
 coord_flip()
```

you can see output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uATiL.jpg).

[image]

I reckon I'm asking for something trivial. I want the text labels to "follow" stacked bars. Labels are placed correctly on the y-axis, but how to position them correctly on x-axis?

Comment: Yepp... I should've posted this one on ggplot2 mailing list. I don't want to cross-post, so I'm going to put on my patience hat and wait for @hadley to come up with something! =)

Comment: I was wrong. And I need to get more acquainted with the ggplot package apparently.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(bar) + 
  geom_col(aes(variable, `(all)`, fill = ustanova), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(variable, `(all)`, label = sprintf("%2.1f", `(all)`), group = ustanova), 
            position = position_dodge(width = .9)) +
  coord_flip()
```

The key is to `position = position_dodge(width = .9)` (where `.9` is the default width of the bars) instead of `position = "dodge"`, which is just a shortcut without any parameter. Additionally you have to set the `group=ustanova` aesthetic in `geom_text` to dodge the labels by `ustanova` (A second option would be to make `fill = ustanova` a global aesthetic via `ggplot(bar, aes(fill = ustanova))`

[image]

---

In `ggplot2_2.0.0` you find several examples in `?geom_text` on how to position `geom_text` on dodged or stacked bars (the code chunk named "`# Aligning labels and bars"`). The Q&A [What is the width argument in position_dodge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge) provides a more thorough description of the topic.

Comment: So is there no way to automate this? One must always specify the width?

Comment: This only worked for me after I added `fill = ustanova` in the `geom_text` layer which makes sense especially when you have many horizontal bars (maybe only needed for 3+ bars per x) and the number of breaks must be the same for the text as it is for the bars.

Comment: For facetted and dodged this is a useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26661791/1000343

Comment: important to mention that the standard dodge is .9 in `position_dodge()`. I'd generally avoid combining methods `position = "dodge"` and `position = position_dodge()` for exactly that reason that you might get unexpected results.