# label a dodged bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Maybe it's because of the dark outside, but I can't get this

[Position geom_text on dodged barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017460/ggplot-geom-text-with-dodged-barplot)

to work on my fairly simple dataframe

```
fs <- data.frame(productcategory=c("c2","c2"), product=c("p4", "p5"), ms1=c(2,1))

plot <- ggplot(data=NULL)
plot + 
    geom_bar(data=fs, aes(x=productcategory, y=ms1, weight=ms1, fill=product),stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
    geom_text(data=fs, aes(label = ms1,  x = productcategory, y=ms1+0.2), position=position_dodge(width=1)))
```

My plot still shows the labels in the "middle" of the product category and not above of the proper product.

Looks like this even it seems very simple, but I'm totally stuck on this

So any hints are very much appreciated how to get labels above the proper bars.

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have the aesthetics defined for each geom individually, `geom_text` isn't picking up on the fact that you're subdividing the x variable `productcategory` by the fill variable `product`.

You can get the graph you want by adding `fill=product` to the `aes()` call for `geom_text`, or you can try to define as many aesthetics as possible in the original `ggplot()` call, so that all the geoms pick up on those aesthetics automatically and you only have to define them if they're specific to that particular geom.

```
plot2 <- ggplot(data=fs, aes(x=productcategory, y=ms1, fill=product)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=ms1, y =ms1 + 0.2), position=position_dodge(width=1))
print(plot2)
```