# ggplot2::geom_box(): how to summarize (x, fill) pairs?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label

I can easily create grouped box plots from the diamonds data set:

```
dd = diamonds[diamonds$color %in% c("E","J"),]
ggplot(dd, aes(x=cut, y=carat)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=color), outlier.shape=NA)

# note: below does *not* work for `geom_text()`
ggplot(dd, aes(x=cut, y=carat, fill=color)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
```

[image]

How can I label each `x` group defined by the `fill` variable?

I am looking for a solution using `stat_summary()` between each `x` pair, to compute e.g. the p-value between each red and green pair below

This roughly corresponds to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876505/boxplot-show-the-value-of-mean), but the difference is that here the data is grouped by `fill` and I want to label those groups.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by differences between `fill`? Perhaps difference in the `mean` values?

Comment: I tried to rephrase above. I'm looking for a general solution to compare, for each `x`, the two groups defined by `fill`. An easy example would be to report p-values for difference in `carat` within each `cut` above.

Comment: Have you tried with `geom_text()`? It's a relatively common question: possible duplicates [dupe 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23328913/903061), [dupe 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23330279/903061), lots more if you can generalize from a dodged barplot:  [dupe 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6017460/903061), [dupe 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10989110/903061), [dupe 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12018499/903061) (the `geom_text` is basically the same in both cases).

Comment: Though I don't think I've seen an answer using `stat_summary`, so I think it would improve your question (and remove my temptation to close it as a duplicate) if you focus only on that possibility.