# Add text on top of a faceted dodged bar chart

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

**I'd like to plot a dodged barplot for two different years and put the revenue numbers on top of the bar accordingly.** After trying quite some suggestion I found over here, I still can't quite get what I want (all the numbers were displayed in the middle of the middle bars/columns instead of spreading equally). Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

**My latest attempt**

```
# Disable scientific notation
options("scipen" = 100, "digits" = 1)

censusData <- structure(list(Year = c(2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 
                                      2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 
                                      2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L, 2012L, 2007L
                                      ), 
                             County = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "Sum", "Sum", "A", 
                                      "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "Sum", "Sum", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
                                      "C", "Sum", "Sum"), 
                             variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                      3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Total_Revenue", "Crop_Revenue", "Livestock_Revenue"
                                      ), class = "factor"), 
                             value = c(1645.51, 1203.806, 68.911, 60.949, 
                                      923.163, 525.918, 2637.584, 1790.673, 1069.497, 787.459, 47.157, 
                                      38.735, 825.050228, 470.024, 1941.704228, 1296.218, 576.013, 
                                      416.347, 21.754, 22.214, 98.112772, 55.894, 695.879772, 494.455)), 
                        row.names = c(NA, -24L), 
                        .Names = c("Year", "County", "variable", "value"), 
                        class = "data.frame")

# Dodged barplot
qbarplot_yr_1 <- ggplot(censusData, aes(County, value)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Year) +  
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  xlab("County") + 
  ylab("Revenue (Million USD)") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = 'Legend', labels = c("Total", "Crop", "Livestocks")) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = 'dark grey')) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "dark grey"))

# Add text on top of the bar
qbarplot_yr_1 + 
  geom_text(data = censusData,
            aes(x = County, y = value + 150, label = format(value, nsmall = 0, scientific = FALSE)), 
            color = "blue")
```

[image: ggplot2 output]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to dodge the text values as well. Try

```
qbarplot_yr_1 + geom_text(data = censusData,
         aes(x = County, group=variable, y = value + 150, 
         label = format(value, nsmall = 0, digits=1, scientific = FALSE)), 
         color="blue", position=position_dodge(.9), hjust=.5)
```

We also need the `group=` so it knows which values to dodge on.

Comment: THANK YOU.  Don't know why I overlooked including the `group` in my `geom_text()` calls but this saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Add another solution using the [`ggfittex`](https://github.com/wilkox/ggfittext) package

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfittext)

ggplot(censusData, 
       aes(County, value,
           fill = variable,
           label = format(value, 
                          nsmall = 0, 
                          big.mark   = ",",
                          scientific = FALSE))) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Year) +  
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +

  # from `ggfittext`
  geom_bar_text(position = "dodge") +

  scale_fill_discrete(name = 'Legend', labels = c("Total", "Crop", "Livestocks")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(face = 'bold'))
```

[image: output]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>