# Obtaining 4 barplots in a panel - error obtained running a previous stackoverflow example

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to create a panel of 4 barplots using ggplot.  This stack overflow post contains an example: [Simple bar plot with multiple variables in R - Similar to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916042/simple-bar-plot-with-multiple-variables-in-r-similar-to-excel)

When I run the code, I obtain an error because there obviously is no variable called "variable". I would appreciate advice regarding how I can run this code.

```
library(ggplot2)

Unit <- c("A", "B", "C", "D") #character objects need quotes
Yes <- c(50, 65, 20, 41)
No <- c(70, 67, 40, 20)
Missing <- c(10, 12, 8, 7)
df <- data.frame(Unit, Yes, No, Missing)

require(tidyr)
df.long <- gather(df, Unit)
colnames(df.long) <- c("Unit", "variable", "value")
```

> Error in names(x) <- value : 
>    'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]

```
ggplot(data = df.long, aes(x = Unit, y = value, fill = variable)) +
       geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'variable' not found

Comment: Seems the gather line is wrong (or from older version of tidyr). Try `df.long <- gather(df, "key","value", -Unit)`. Tested with `tidyr_0.8.1`

Comment: @Parfait What version of `tidyr` did you test with?

Comment: Change to `gather(df, variable,value, -Unit)` and it works. Can also exclude the `colnames(df.long)` statement.

Comment: I'll test this when I get to work, thanks .Tidyr version looks to be tidyr (>= 0.7.2)

Comment: Many thanks - worked perfectly