# I want to represent one persons numerical data graphically on rstudio

Tags: r, excel

I have data on excel and I want to represent one persons data graphically in bar charts beside each other. All the values are numerical and I want it to look something like this:

[image]

where the w,x,y represent different variables like games played and turnovers and the three colours represent three different people. I have data on 20 people.

I don't know how to single out the individual data or represent multiple data points on the [barchart](/questions/tagged/barchart).
Any questions, I'll try to describe as best as I can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can construct stacked bar plots using `ggplot()` (take a look [here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple bar plot with multiple variables in R - Similar to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916042/simple-bar-plot-with-multiple-variables-in-r-similar-to-excel)

Comment: Thanks.. That helps