# R ggplot geom_bar count number of values by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, facet, geom-bar

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634148/issue-with-geom-text-when-using-position-dodge) code without faceting, it works.

I want to add counts on each bar and use facets in my plot, it brokes. I managed to make it close to what I want, like this:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear, am, vs) %>% summarize(hp_sum = sum(hp), hp = hp) %>%
ggplot(aes(gear, hp_sum, fill = factor(am))) + facet_grid(.~vs) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', alpha = 0.5, size = 0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(label=..count.., y = ..count..), stat='count', position = position_dodge(width = 0.95), size=4)
```

[image]

But I want the number on top of each bar. If I use `y = hp_sum`, I got error:

```
Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I might have format the dataset in the wrong way. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I learned from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846348/add-number-of-observations-per-group-in-ggplot2-boxplot) post that `geom_text` does not do counts by groups.

A solution is to do the summary beforehand:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear, am, vs) %>% 
  summarize(hp_sum = sum(hp), count = length(hp)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(gear, hp_sum, fill = factor(am))) + facet_grid(.~vs) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge', alpha = 0.5, size = 0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(gear, hp_sum, label = count), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.95), size=4)
```

Be sure to group data the same way in the plot. Here `x=gear, facet_grid(.~vs), fill = factor(am)` are three factors putting `y=hp` into groups. So you should group this way: `group_by(gear, am, vs)`. Hope this helps anyone who is struggling with this issue.

[plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQEwG.png)