# geom_text with dodged barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I try to add text as in [Position geom_text on dodged barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017460/ggplot-geom-text-with-dodged-barplot)
But its not work with my simple data

```
data=data.frame(s=c(10,13,17,8),
                pr=c("a","b","a","b"),
                m=c(rep(as.Date('01.01.2015','%d.%m.%Y'),2), rep(as.Date('01.02.2015','%d.%m.%Y'),2)))
```

And ggplot

```
ggplot(data = data 
       ,aes(x = m, y = s,fill=pr ,ymax = max(s)*1.1))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(y=s/2,label=paste(round(s,3),"%")),position = position_dodge(width=1))+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%y"),breaks = date_breaks("months"))
```

i get

[image]

How to add text in right position( in the middle of each bar)?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `width=30` instead of `width=1` and it will work

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2 (  `ggplot(data = data, aes(x = as.factor(m), y = s,fill=pr ,ymax = max(s)*1.1)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") + geom_text(aes(y=s/2,label=paste(round(s,3),"%")),position = position_dodge(.9)) + scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%m/%y"))`   ).

Comment: LyzandeR is right, here the widths of columns are not equal to 1, they correspond to the number of days in months. As for me, better than setting width to 30 (because we have months with 31 and 28 days) is converting dates to factor as lukeA adviced

Comment: I try `width=30` , but in some months i get text not in the middle( look not pretty). @lukeA Its realy good( you can post it as answer), thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = as.factor(m), y = s,fill=pr ,ymax = max(s)*1.1)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(y=s/2,label=paste(round(s,3),"%")),position = position_dodge(.9)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%m/%y")) + 
  xlab("m")
```