# Cannot get position_dodge to work with grouped barplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a rather simple graphing project and cannot get the `position_dodge` code to work for my triple grouped bar plot in ggplot2.

My small melted data frame is here:

```
structure(list(month = c(6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Min", "Max", "Avg"
), class = "factor"), value = c(1.3, 2.52258064516129, 4.28709677419355, 
1.85666666666667, 2.13870967741935, 4.06129032258064, 1.56666666666667, 
2.32903225806452, 4.16129032258065)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("month", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

The plot code that works does not contain `position_dodge` which is here:

```
ggplot(PJM.data, aes(x= factor(month), y= value, fill = variable)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
geom_text(aes(label= paste(round(value, digits = 1), "°F", sep = ""), vjust= -0.25))+
scale_fill_manual("Temperature Mean", values= c("steelblue","firebrick1","gold2"))+ ggtitle("Summer 2016 PJM Temperatures") +
labs(y= "Temperature Anomaly°F")
```

It produces this image:

[image]

Every time I attempt to add `position_dodge` into my `geom_text` portion of my code, the plot trips up and gives me this error:

```
   Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type PositionDodge/Position/ggproto. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): label, vjust, position, x, y, fill
```

I've attempted to change the width value of the position_dodge to many different values and even included the same argument into the geom_bar section. I've consulted both similar posts ([Position geom_text on dodged barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017460/position-geom-text-on-dodged-barplot?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Position geom_text on dodged barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017460/position-geom-text-on-dodged-barplot?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but I cannot figure out why those simple solutions don't work for my data.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: as per one of the solutions you link to, you need `width = 1` : `geom_text(aes(label= paste(round(value, digits = 1), "°F", sep = ""), vjust= -0.25), position = position_dodge(width = 1))`

Comment: Wow... Just a comma misplaced on my code. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: no problem - just FYI, questions that are solved due to a typo typically get closed on StackOverflow

Comment: Probably a good idea here. I'll try to do that. Thanks