# Adding a count stat text to ggplot geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add the number count stat above each bar:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=color, fill=cut)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label=after_stat(count)), vjust=0)
```

It's giving me the error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be valid computed stats. Problematic aesthetic(s): label = after_stat(count).
> Did you map your stat in the wrong layer?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6017460/680068

Comment: Try with `geom_text(aes(label=after_stat(count)), vjust=0, stat = "count")`. Otherwise you have stat = "identity" and no "count" is computed.